# Creating a more specific report within Sql/php script

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I have a pretty dense sql query running within a php script that basically aggregates numbers for each of our employees on the phone, creates a CSV and then attaches it for email through PHP mailer.

This works fine but I've been tasked with making it into a full report (i.e. excel report, formatted,etc.) with totals for each employee. Right now it basically just has line items for each employee so employee A might have 32 records and then it goes right to Employee B. I need to change it so that at the end of Employee A's records, it inserts a row that totals the values for each column.

I figure I could possibly do this just using PHP, since this is in a PHP script, but I don't know the best way to do that here and I'm hoping for some guidance that I can apply to the rest of the query.

I'm thinking it may be good to create a variable for fields/columns so that I can create a SUM that way but I'm in over my head on that.

Here's the SQL portion of the script:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn2,
    "SELECT
        FirstN
        , LastN
        , Extension
        , Recieved
        , Recieved_Known
        , Outbound
        , Outbound_Known
        , Missed_No_VM
        , Missed_VM
        , Missed_Known
        , Calling_Number
        , Called_Number
        , Start_Time
        , End_Time
        , Talk_Time_Seconds
        , Hold_Time_Seconds

        FROM (
          SELECT distinct
           firstn
           , lastn
           , c.extension
           , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Recieved
           , case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Recieved_Known
           , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 then 'x' ELSE '' end  AS Outbound
           , case when  FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = kn.long_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Outbound_Known
           , case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 0 and finallycalledpartyno  not like '%oice%' then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_No_VM
           , case when finallycalledpartyno like '%oice%' then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_VM
           , case when legtype1 = 2 and ANSWERED = 0 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as
            Missed_Known
           , a.CALLINGPARTYNO AS Calling_Number
           , a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO AS Called_Number
           , b.starttime as Start_Time
           , b.endtime as End_Time
           , b.duration as Talk_Time_Seconds
           , a.holdtimesecs as Hold_Time_Seconds

          FROM ambition.session a
            INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
            right join jackson_id.users c on a.callingpartyno = c.extension or a.finallycalledpartyno = c.extension
            LEFT JOIN ambition.known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
        left join ambition.known_numbers kn on a.finallycalledpartyno = kn.long_number
                WHERE a.ts >= '2017-12-07' -- curdate()
                and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users) OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from ambition.ambition_users))
          ) x
          order by extension;") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));
```

And a screenshot of the current CSV:
[image]

As you can see it goes from agent 7200 to agent 7206. But I need to insert a row that totals those x's in each column.

Comment: Please give us an output example so we can understand what totals of x's is.

Answer (score 0):

Try the https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel library, it's great for creating Excel files and you can probably add in formulae to do the adding up.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I think csv or excel, that's not his question.